# There is one part of Baby Rudin's Theorem 7.23 that I do not understand.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The theorem is following.

If $\{f_n\}$ is a pointwise bounded sequence of complex functions on a countable set E, then $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $\{f_{n_k}(x)\}$ converges for every $x\in E$.

Proof

Let $\{x_i\}, i=1,2,3,\ldots$, be the points of E, arranged in a sequence. Since $\{f_n(x_1)$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence, which we shall denote by $\{f_{1,k}\}$, such that $\{f_{1,k}(x_1)\}$ converges as $k\to\infty$.

Let us now consider sequences $S_1$,$S_2$,$S_3$,$\ldots$, which we represent by the array

$$
S_1:f_{1,1}f_{1,2}f_{1,3}f_{1,4}\cdots
\\\,S_2:f_{2,1}f_{2,2}f_{2,3}f_{2,4}\cdots
\\\,S_3:f_{3,1}f_{3,2}f_{3,3}f_{3,4}\cdots
\\\,\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots
$$

and which have the following properties:

(a) $S_n$ is a subsequence of $S_{n−1}$, for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$

(b) $\{f_{n,k}(x_n)\}$ converges, as $k\to\infty$ (the boundedness of $\{f_n(x_n)\}$ make it possible to choose $S_n$ in this way);

(c) The order in which the functions appear is the same in each sequence; i.e., if one function precedes another in $S_1$, they are in the same relation in every $S_n$,until one or the other is deleted. Hence, when going from one row in the above array to the next blow, functions ,may move to the left but never to the right.

We now go down the diagonal of the array; i.e, we consider the sequence

$$
S:f_{1,1}f_{2,2}f_{3,3}f_{4,4}\ldots.
$$

By (c), the sequence $S$ (except possibly its first $n−1$ terms) is a subsequence of $S_n$, for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Hence (b) implies that $\{f_{n,n}(x_i)\}$ converges, as $n\to\infty$, for every $x_i\in E$.

The end of Proof.

My question is why is (c) necessary? From (a) and the definition of the subsequence, the element of each $S_n$ (ex. $f_{1,1}$) is ordered, so condition (c) is not needed?

(I am new to this site and my English is not very good, sorry if I used some rude expressions.)

Comment: Everything would be clear if we write formally: A subsequence $g$ of a sequence $f$ is simply a function of the form $g = f\circ \theta$, where $\theta:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition (c) prohibits situations where, for example, both $f_{1,3}$ and $f_{1,8}$ are in the subsequence $S_2$, but out of order, perhaps $f_{1,3}=f_{2,75}$ and $f_{1,8}=f_{2,2}$. In the prohibited situation, $S_2$ would not be a subsequence of $S_1$ (even though the *set* of terms in $S_1$ is a subset of the set of terms of $S_2$). In the absence of condition (c), such maneuvers (and more complicated shuffles) would be allowed (at every stage of the process that produces the $S_n$'s) and such shuffling could completely mess  up the diagonal sequence $S$. For example, you could use Rudin's $S_n$ but re-order the terms in each $S_n$  to interchange some useless term in $S_n$ with the diagonal element $f_{n,n}$. Then your new diagonal sequence $S$ would consist of all those useless terms, and (barring extreme luck) the diagonal sequence wouldn't converge as the theorem claims.

A rough summary of the preceding paragraph is that, after getting each $S_n$ to converge at $x_n$, you need the diagonal sequence $S$ to be, except for finitely many terms, a subsequence of (or at least seriously related to) all these $S_n$'s. And if each $S_n$ might have been shuffled at will, there's no way to ensure that. So (c) says "don't shuffle."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it has not yet been resolved. As you say, I understand 'don't shuffle'. (Indeed, if there is shuffling, convergence seems difficult.) However, I feel that this is forbidden in the first place from (a), because preserve the order of the subscripts (by the definiton of subsequences). For example, the possibility that f1,3=f2,75, f1,8=f2,2 feels zero, since S2 is a subsequence (by (a)) of S1. (The term obtained by f1,3 cannot come later than f1,8.)

Comment: Actually, even without condition (c), the situation that "both $f_{1,3}$ and $f_{1,8}$ are in the subsequence $S_2$, but out of order, perhaps $f_{1,3}=f_{2,75}$ and $f_{1,8}=f_{2,2}$" would not happen.  For example, if $(y_{k})_{k}$ is a subsequence of $(x_{k})_{k}$,
then $y_{k}=x_{n_{k}}$ , where the indices $n_{k}$ must satisfy
the condition: $1\leq n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$. From which, we can prove
by induction that $k\leq n_{k}$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Condition (c) indeed repeats (probably for emphasis) the "subsequence" in condition (a). As I said, shuffling would produce a subset but not a subsequence.

Comment: I did not see the need for condition (c), but if it was for the reason of emphasis, it made sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the classical Cantor's diagonal argument. In order to make
it precise, firstly we clarify the notion of subsequence:

Let $X$ be a set (for example, $X=\mathbb{R}$, $X=\mathbb{C}$, or $X=\mathbb{C}^E$ (the set of all complex-valued functions defined on $E$) ).
A sequence of $X$ is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$. We
denote $f(n)$ by $f_{n}$. Given a sequence $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$,
a subsequence $g$ of $f$ is a function of the form: $g=f\circ\theta$,
where $\theta:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing
function. It is easy to prove (by mathematical induction) that $\theta(k)\geq k$.

Usually, we denote $\theta(k)$ by $n_{k}$. Hence, we write $g(k)=f(\theta(k))=f_{n_{k}}$.

---

Now we go back to the construction of $f_{n,k}$.

Since $\left(f_{n}(x_{1})\right)_{n}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{C}$,
by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, we can choose a subsequence $(f_{1,k})_{k}$
of $(f_{k})$ such that $\left(f_{1,k}(x_{1})\right)_{k}$ converges
as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Now, consider the sequence $(f_{1,k})_{k}$. Since $(f_{1,k}(x_{2}))_{k}$
is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem
again, we can choose a subsequence $(f_{2,k})_{k}$ of $(f_{1,k})$
such that $(f_{2,k}(x_{2}))_{k}$ converges as $k\rightarrow\infty$.
To be precise, there are actually strictly increasing functions $\theta_{1},\theta_{2}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$
such that $f_{1,k}=f\circ\theta_{1}(k)$ and $f_{2,k}=f_{1,\theta_{2}(k)}=(f\circ\theta_{1})\circ\theta_{2}(k)$.
Observe that $(f_{2,k}(x_{1}))_{k}$ is a subsequence of the converging
sequence $(f_{1,k}(x_{1}))_{k}$, so $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(f_{2,k}(x_{1}))_{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(f_{1,k}(x_{1}))_{k}$.

Repeating the process inductively, we obtain strictly increasing functions
$\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\ldots:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such
that $f_{n,k}=f\circ\theta_{1}\circ\cdots\circ\theta_{n}(k)$. The
sequence $(f_{n,k})_{k}$ has the property that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{n,k}(x_{i})$
converges for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Finally, define $g_{k}=f_{k,k}$. We go to show that:

1. $(g_{k})_{k}$ is a subsequence of $(f_{k})_{k}$
2. $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}g_{k}(x_{i})$ converges for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

Define $\psi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ by $\psi(k)=\theta_{1}\circ\cdots\circ\theta_{k}(k)$.
We check that $\psi$ is strictly increasing: Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Note that $\theta_{k+1}(k+1)\geq k+1>k$ and $\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{k}$
is strictly increasing, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi(k+1) & = & \left(\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{k}\right)\theta_{k+1}(k+1)\\
 & > & \left(\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{k}\right)(k)\\
 & = & \psi(k).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $g=f\circ\psi$ is a subsequence of $f$.

Next, let $i\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Denote $l=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{i,k}(x_{i})$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $K\geq i$ such that $\left|f_{i,k}(x_{i})-l\right|<\varepsilon$
whenever $k\geq K$. If we look closely, it means that
$$
\left|f\circ(\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{i})(k)-l\right|<\varepsilon
$$
whenever $k\geq K$. For $k\geq K$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|g(k)-l\right|\\
 & = & \left|f\circ(\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{i}\theta_{i+1}\cdots\theta_{k})(k)-l\right|\\
 & = & \left|f\circ(\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{i})(k')-l\right|
\end{eqnarray*}
where $k'=\theta_{i+1}\cdots\theta_{k}(k)$. Clearly $k'\geq k\geq K$,
so $\left|f\circ(\theta_{1}\cdots\theta_{i})(k')-l\right|<\varepsilon$.
This shows that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}g_{k}(x_{i})$ converges
for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for the proof. I now have a better understanding of the theorem. However, I see that you use conditions (a) and (b) of the theorem, but do you use (c)? Is 'strictly increasing' inspired by (a) rather than (c)?

Comment: In defining "subsequence", the function $\theta : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ must be strctily increasing. If $\theta$ is merely increasing, i.e., $\theta(k)\leq \theta(k+1)$, $\theta$ may be a constant. For example, $\theta(k)=1$ for all $k$. If we use this to define "subsequence", say $g = f \circ \theta$, then $g_1 = f_1$, $g_2=f_1$, .... Obviously, this is not what we want.

Comment: I had only looked at Rudin's proof, thinking only of the need for condition (c). However, I realised that it is important to prove it freely, as you did. Thank you!